# Unable to deploy a war file in tomcat 8

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy a WAR in tomcat server. I've successfully built a WAR file using

```
mvn package
```

When I try to deploy it using tomcat 8.5.31 through Manager App, I get this error:

```
Network Error (tcp_error)
- 503 error - A communication error occurred: ""
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems 
preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a 
later time.
```

What are the reasons of the non-deployment of the WAR?
any help ! Thanks.

Comment: Does your application actually work? Did you test it with build-in-IDE tomcat or with tomcat7-maven-plugin?

Comment: Do you have a reverse proxy (e.g. apache httpd, nginx, etc) server in front of your Tomcat server?   Are you attempting to deploy through the reverse proxy?

Comment: hello @user1516873. I'm using STS, when I test my app, it runs perfectly.

Comment: hello @StephenC. No I'm not using reverse proxy. The problem is that I'm able to deploy another war. I'm wondering if the problem is related to application.properties. Does connection to the database can affect the deployment of the war file?

Answer (score 1):

**Check your Proxy setting:**

1. Open internet option in IE.
2. Goto LAN setting in Connection option.
3. In LAN Setting there is advance setting tab, click it.
4. You will see a Exception box at the bottom.
5. Type the IP Address form which you want access. eg. 10.200;*.xyz.com
6. This setting is to be done on system from where you want to access
   your web application.

**Secondly you can do this:**

add this to virtualhost

```
<Proxy *>
     AddDefaultCharset Off
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Proxy>
```